# How to Provide Default Values for List-valued Spring Environment Properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated class that uses a nested subtype and several of those can be configured as a list, like so:

```java
@Data
@Validated
@NoArgsConstructor
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = AcmeKafkaConfigurationProperties.PREFIX)
public class AcmeKafkaConfigurationProperties {
  public static final String PREFIX = "com.acme.kafka";

  @NotEmpty(message = "Instances must not be null or empty.")
  private List<ServiceInstance> instances;

  @Data
  @Validated
  @NoArgsConstructor
  public static final class ServiceInstance {

    @NotBlank(message = "Acme Kafka service instance name must not be blank.")
    private String name;

    @NotBlank(message = "Username must not be blank. Make sure it is either specified explicitly or available from VCAP_SERVICES environment.")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message = "Password must not be blank. Make sure it is either specified explicitly or available from VCAP_SERVICES environment.")
    private String password;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Brokers must not be empty. Make sure it is either specified explicitly or available from VCAP_SERVICES environment.")
    private List<@NotBlank String> brokers;

    @NotNull(message = "Token endpoint URL must not be null and must be a valid URL. Make sure it is either specified explicitly or available from VCAP_SERVICES environment.")
    private URL tokenEndpoint;

    @NotNull(message = "Token validity must not be null and a value given in seconds (1s), minutes (2m), hours (3h), or days (365d).")
    @DurationUnit(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
    private Duration tokenValidity = Duration.ofDays(3650);

    private String springCloudStreamBinderName;

    private boolean isDefault;
  }
}
```

I want the user to HAVE to provide the `name` of each service instance, but allow them to omit the other `ServiceInstance` properties. If they are omitted, I want to default their values from the environment, i.e. they should be references to `${vcap.services.....some-property}`.

I am using an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` to try and add to the environment the missing (defaulted) configurations like so:

```java
 private void addDefaults(ConfigurableEnvironment environment) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    properties.put("com.acme.kafka.instances[0].username",       "${vcap.services.my-kafka-instance.credentials.username:}");
    properties.put("com.acme.kafka.instances[0].password",       "${vcap.services.my-kafka-instance.credentials.password:}");
    properties.put("com.acme.kafka.instances[0].brokers",        "${vcap.services.my-kafka-instance.credentials.cluster.brokers:}");
    properties.put("com.acme.kafka.instances[0].token-endpoint", "${vcap.services.my-kafka-instance.credentials.urls.token:}");

    environment.getPropertySources().addLast(new PropertiesPropertySource("AcmeKafka", properties));
    ConfigurationPropertySources.attach(environment);
  }
```

But when I am binding the `AcmeKafkaConfigurationProperties` class above, the added values are never bound. The respective properties just remain null.
If I am adding the PropertySource using `addFirst()` they are bound, but the ones given by the user are not.

What's the proper way to add list-valued properties to the environment?